# page is not working properly on small screen

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive

My page is working properly on bigger screen size devices but on mobile devices it is not working properly. please help

https://codesandbox.io/s/ships-q64g6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Could you create a Minimal Example rather than redirecting to an other website ? it would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #00171f;

}

.App h4 {
  font-size: 25.5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.container ul {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container li {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 1.5em;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}


.container .name {
  max-width: 660px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #57e1ed;
}

.container .port {
  margin-top: -20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: right;
  color: #57e1ed;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my hours of banging head on the debugging. but the names below image are not getting aligned properly on big screen now.

Comment: Thank you so much. it's working perfectly. could you please point out what i was doing wrong or the things you done to get it right. It will be really helpful for me.

Comment: the images width was fixed to 800px, and you didnt set width to the ul element.